How to replace internal packge data in R testthat
I have an R package in which I use internal data set with usethis::use_data internal = TRUE, and saved to a sysdata.rda in my R folder. When running my unittests however, I would like to 'overwrite' / replace on of my internal data.frames with a mock one.
To simplify, this is how I have set up my package:
create_data.R
# Internal package data
df <- data.frame(test = c(1, 2, 3))
usethis::use_data(df, internal = TRUE)

R/show_me_values.R
# This the function I wish to test
show_me_values <- function() {
  return(df)
}

test/testthat/test-show_me_values.R
test_that("Test that my function uses mock data", {
  expect_equal(show_me_values(), data.frame(test = c(1, 1, 1)))
})

I have tried to set a mock df using local_mocked_bindings i setup.R like this:
test/testthat/setup.R
local_mocked_bindings(
  df = data.frame(test = c(1, 1, 1))
)

I have also tried to play around with assign and withr::local_environment - but so far nothing..
How do I get my show_me_values function, to use mock data?
What works:
If I add
local_mocked_bindings(
  df = data.frame(test = c(1, 1, 1))
)

inside the test_that function or just in a test file, it will apply the mock data to that specific test or all the tests in that file.
However, I'm looking for a way to have local_mocked_bindings applied to all my tests, in all of my test files.

I don't think you can "get show_me_values to use mock data": from the code you share, the value returned by show_me_values is hard-coded.  But what you can do is mock show_me_values itself to return something else.  Or modify the existing show_me_values so that it's aware if it is being run in a test environment or not [testthat::is_testing()] - although I don't think that's a good idea.  BTW, you know your current test will fail, right?

Well, if I move local_mocked_bindings into the test_that function itself, it works. However, I would like to mock my data for all tests in all my test files. But if I run local_mocked_bindings in setup.R - it fails...

setup.R is superseded.  You should be able to get the same effect using calls to withr functions in the same file as the tests.  See here - in particular the "Scope" section.  I've used this approach, and it works.  Though I admit I've not used it with local_mocked_bindings().

Well, the scope section mentions "To run code before any test is run, you can create a file called tests/testthat/setup.R"? That's pretty much way I choose to use setup.R - but maybe I have misunderstood something here?

I gave you the wrong link under "superseded".  My apologies.  Here is the correct one.  It reads in part "We no longer recommend using setup() and teardown(); instead we think it's better practice to use a test fixture as described in vignette("test-fixtures")".  I cannot see the text you quote in any part of the vignette.  I'm looking at the documentation for testthat v3.2.1.

But is that for the function 'setup()' or also for the use of setup.R inside the testthat folder (as they recommend in the scope section here https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/test-fixtures.html#scope ?
I any case, I'm not sure as to where I should then place local_mocked_bindings as to only run it ones, and have it applied to all my tests in all my test files?

From the test fixtures link above: "If you move the local_() call outside of a test_that() block, it will affect all tests that come after it. This means that by calling the test fixture at the top of the file you can change the behaviour for all tests. ".

R function are lexically scoped, meaning they are looking for the variable in their imbricated definition scopes.
But you can assign a new environment to a function with environment function.
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5)

function () print(df)

func()


  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5

Then, changing the environment:
myenv = new.env()
myenv$df <- data.frame(z = 4:8)
environment(func) <- myenv
func()

  z
1 4
2 5
3 6
4 7
5 8


PS: A far better way of doing thing is to not use global variables but define a parameter to
show_me_values <- function(df = data.frame(test = c(1, 2, 3))) {
  return(df)
}

Or, using a lexical closure to not pollute the global environment
show_me_values <- (
  function () 
  {
    default = data.frame(test = c(1, 2, 3))
    function (df = default) { return(df) } 
  })()

show_me_values()

  test
1    1
2    2
3    3

show_me_values(df = data.frame(z=1))

  z
1 1

